# Simulate domains locally in ASP.NET /IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis

I would like to simulate that my ASP.NET application is hist by say simdomain.com.

How can i do that easily?

Ideally I would like some kind of filter, so requests to certain domains are routed to localhost, and it should be easy to turn it on and off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file).

1. Run `notepad c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
2. Add the following line:

   127.0.0.1      simdomain.com
3. Open IIS admin and add a "simdomain.com" website. So it knows the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Try editing you local hosts file. The default location is %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts in most Windows systems.

Then you simply add the line

```
127.0.0.1       simdomain.com
```

That should do it.

EDIT: Ah, and as Chakrit said: Open IIS admin and add a "simdomain.com" website. So it knows the domain.

This depends a bit on IIS version, but if I remember correctrly for IIS7 do as follows:

1. Run 'inetmgr', or access the IIS setings via the Control Panel.
2. In the menu on the left open 'Sites', and right-click on the site you want to access. Choose 'Edit bindings..'
3. Click add. Type: Http, IP Address: All Unassigned, Port: 80, Host name: simdomain.com then click OK.

Might as well make my answer correct, even if the post is a tad redundant. ;)

Comment: About "Open IIS admin"  - the point for me is to have a multi-domain site, so i don't think I need to do that - perhaps for cross-domain javascript of cookies?

(Dont have it quite working jet - at a ping level. - Olav)

Comment: No, you need to add a "listener" to the site in IIS, otherwise it won't pick up on requests. I'll add how you do that to my responce.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a read of this SO discussion; ["ASP.NET Development server or localhost IIS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281667/asp-net-development-server-or-localhost-iis/)