# What is the difference between IIS server and development server provided by Visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-development-serv

Can anyone please tell me the difference between IIS Server and Development server provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: Anything specific you have in mind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a few links to read up on :-)

[Core Differences Between IIS and the ASP.NET Development Server](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/core-differences-between-iis-and-the-asp-net-development-server-cs)

[ASP.NET Development Server or Localhost IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281667/asp-net-development-server-or-localhost-iis)

[What are the (dis)advantages of using Cassini instead of IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103785/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-cassini-instead-of-iis#104264)

I don't know why your looking into this but you might want to take a look at IIS Express - [Introducing IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are MANY differences, some of them:

1. Local access in Cassini
2. Cassini does not support S
3. Cassini runs as your account (whoever is logged on), IIS runs as a service which means some things change quite a bit
4. Does not support authentication methods like Basic, Digest, etc.
5. Does not run any of the IIS Modules, which means you will not be able to do things like URL Rewrite, Default Documents, Directory Browsing, Custom Errors for static pages, etc
6. Does not support things like Virtual Directories, etc.

What I would recommend for anyone wanting something as simple as Cassini, yet more compatible is to use IIS Express which supports almost all features from IIS yet with a much simplified model suited for development http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx. Visual Studio will include support for it.