# Needed help ralated to Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webserver

I have installed OS Windows7 Home Basic at my development machine. After developing the ASP.NET web application, I needed to deploy. I started installing IIS on my machine, but found that in Win7 Home Basic, there is no iis manager. After searching on net, I found Cassine Web Server(CWS). I installed the CWS and it working fine as a web server.

I have a question. Is CWS is better than IIS? Is CWS is secured as IIS? Is CWS can be used as a web server at target machines?

If anyone used CWS, please tell me about your experience.

Comment: Check the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281667/asp-net-development-server-or-localhost-iis

Answer (score 1):

CWS is just a development web server. It has no purpose to be used as a production web server.

Comment: but as per the CWS site, it can be used at client machine also. I think it may be less secure than IIS.  http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx

Comment: It's absolutely not the same products, in your question it's Microsoft's Cassini aka Visual Studio WebDev in ultidev website, it's not ultidev Cassini.
And based on the ultidev comparison table, ultidev Cassini has a lack of security.