# running asp.net without web server

Tags: asp.net

I am a teacher and will do an exam for a couple of students in basic Asp.Net. During the exam they will only do very easy things, so validation of code behind logic etc is not much of a concern.

My problem is that the IT department cannot set things up so that the students have access to a web server (on a dedicated server for exams). The only thing they have available is Visual Studio 2010. I wonder how much the students can do anyway. For example, they should be able to view the .aspx files in Design view even without a web server installed (or so I presume). Is there a way to actually run an Asp.Net web site without a web server (like one can run a set of HTML pages)? Just to be able to click around, with no real logic involved. Or anything similar?

Comment: If they have Visual Studio 2010, they should be able to run any ASP .NET project using the built-in development server right?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I think you're right but I received the information that this shouldn't be possible and thought that I might hve overlooked something. Hmmm... :)

Comment: It is possible, using on the Visual Studio IDE to run a website locally without a full webserver.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that's what I thought!

Answer (score 3):

If Visual Studio is installed, it can be run on the Visual Studio Development Server. You don't need to do anything else, but keep in mind that it does [not fully represent a production server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281683/783284).

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try myself and see if I can get it to work... :)

Comment: It should work; I don't recall ever having to do anything special other than installing Visual Studio for Cassini to run. I'd be interested to learn if that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks again, It seems as if everyone here agrees, so I'm sure you're all correct.