# Visual studio web server iis6 or iis7?

Tags: visual-studio

When I run my asp.net mvc site in visual studio 2008 is it running iis7 or iis6 Internally?

Also does mvc require iis7 (is intended for?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via Visual Studio, you're not really running IIS6 or IIS7.  You're running Cassini.  You can find out [how Cassini differs from IIS here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103785/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-cassini-instead-of-iis). As for ASP.NET MVC, it may be deployed to run under IIS6 or IIS7.  As mentioned previously, you have to jump through some hoops if you want to run under IIS6 so IIS7 is ideal if possible.  If you are stuck with IIS6 (maybe you're on Windows Server 2003) there are a couple of best practices (Url file extensions or wild card application maps) which Phil Haack has [well documented](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) which will help to get your application running correctly.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the devserver under VS is not cassini (though it is very similar).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the one built in to windows, that is tied to your OS version rather than to your version of Visual Studio.

If you mean the version that Visual Studio uses as a development webserver, then that version is not IIS.  Its an internal webserver (very similar to [Cassini](http://www.asp.net/Downloads/archived/cassini/)) suited for testing and debugging only.

Answer (score 0):

MVC can work in IIS6 but you need to make sure to set your routing to "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}".

As for IIS6 or 7 for the "IISLite" that VS uses, I am unsure of that.  I think VS2008 uses IIS7 because I do not need to add ".aspx" to my controller in the route when debugging.