# Why is my web-app rendered differently in IIS vs in cassini

Tags: iis, cassini

I have created a stock Web App in VS2010. In Cassini the web-app is rendered normally, but in IIS no styles are shown. I am using IIS 7 in Win7

Comment: Sounds like [this caveat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103785/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-cassini-instead-of-iis/104264#104264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a security issue with the folder that the css is stored in.  Easiest way to debug (imo) is using Fiddler or Firebug and seeing what is happening to the request for the css files.

Comment: You are correct, Do you know which permissions to assign to which user for the web-app's folder?

Comment: Its running under some kind of service account (app pool identity or network service or something...check the app pool properties in iis), I believe Read access should be all it needs.  There may be (probably is) some slicker tool or way to do this in a less manual fashion, might want to check out Matt's comment as it looks like it may speak directly to your issue.