# Is webdev.webserver.exe dead?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver, webdev.webserver

I am following an older book and it talks about webdev.webserver.exe to test an APS page. Looks like it used to come with earlier versions of Visual Studio but I don't see in Visual Studio 2019.

Also any references and posts I see about it pretty old.

I am learning ASP.NET and obviously running/testing ASP pages. Should I just work with IIS?

I am using Windows 10 system.

p.s the tag webdev.webserver has only 70 questions to it in all this time :) That re-enforces my question.

Comment: Cassini has been dead for almost a decade now,  https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-asp-net-on-iis-8f49e2bcefcd

Comment: @LexLi I didn't even know it was called Cassini. That book didn't use that name but now I know and look it up better. Thanks.

Comment: So to sum it up, as @LexLi pointed out, it's dead and its better known as Cassini. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103817/841330) might of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Windows 10 system, then you can only use IIS, and IIS can completely replace WebDev.WebServer.

And please note that there is still a difference between APS page and ASP.NET:

[ASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages): ASP stands for Active Server Pages. It is a development framework used for building web pages. ASP was introduced in 1998 by Microsoft as its first server side scripting language. The file extension of ASP pages are .asp and are normally written in VBScript. It is an old but still powerful tool for making dynamic web pages. ASP is a technology (much like PHP) for executing scripts on a web server.

[ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET): ASP.NET was released in 2002 by Microsoft as a successor to ASP. It is also a server-side web framework, open source, which is designed for the generation of dynamic web pages. The file extension of ASP.NET pages are .aspx.